# Is a dependency required to display a graph using chartjs-directive in a mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, code-injection, chart.js, mddialog

I'm trying to display a graph using chartjs-directive in a mdDialog. The graph's data has to be generated in a controller.

I downloaded the directive and one of the documents says:

"Angular Chart-js Directive [Homepage]

Usage

1. Include [chartjs] via script tag, can use bower or download min
2. Include `chartjs-directive.js`.
3. Add `chartjs-directive` as a dependency to your app.
4. Make `<chart>`s."

Bower Installable via `bower`:

```
bash bower install angular-chartjs-directive
```

html

```
<div ng-app="chartjs-directive">
  <chart value="myChart"></chart>
</div>
```

I used this code in the html code of my mdDialog:

```
<div  class="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;" >
    <div ng-app="chartjs-directive">
        <chart value="myChart"></chart>
    </div>
</div>

<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>{{teste}}</label>
</md-input-container>
```

( here, {{teste}} is used to see if the controller is working)

on the top of index html I used:

```
<script src="resources/js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/bower_components/chartjs-directive/chartjs-directive.js"></script>
```

And the controller:

```
function GraphController($scope, $mdDialog, $timeout, $http) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
  $scope.search = function() {
    var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
      },
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
      }
    ]
  };

  $scope.teste = "123456";
  $scope.myChart.data = data;

  };
```

The function search() is called when The user clicks on a button.

It works only for $scope.teste, I can't display the graph... So I tryed to add `chartjs-directive` as a dependency to my controller using this at the top of the controllers script:

I tried to change my function to:

```
function GraphController($scope, $mdDialog, $timeout, $http,'chartjs-directive')
```

My app crashed; I also tried add this code at the top of my controller's script:

```
angular.module('appControllers').controller('GraphController', GraphController);
GraphController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdDialog', '$timeout', '$http','chartjs-directive'];
```

My app crashed again.